# Chat invitation message is not able to localize

Tags: bug, chat, localization, russian-stackoverflow

Look like a chat invitation message is not able to localize:

> [image: join a chat]

I can't find string "You have been invited to join a chat" in transifex DB.

I know that chats are not localizable at all, but this message is used in context of the site and should be allowed to translate.