# "Discussion on question by ..." should be allowed to translate for localized sites

Tags: bug, chat, localization, russian-stackoverflow

When the comments under the post body are migrated to the chat, [chat room name](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83371/discussion-on-question-by-suvitruf-------) is automatically set to `"Discussion on question by {username}: {question-title}"`:

> [image: title]

Such text is not available to translate in Transifex, but it should be.

Related question about interaction between site and chat: [Chat invitation message is not able to localize](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296140/339911)

Comment: Everything regarding the chat is not translated. No?

Comment: @Suvitruf see the last sentence of related post. BTW `chat reply` message is [translated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbk1E.png).